# How to add ItemListeners dynamically?

Tags: java, itemlistener

I'm writing a program to calculate GPA. It consists of several panels. The first panel
tells the user to specify the number of courses so that Comboboxes (gradeCombo),(hourCombo) and Textfields will be added dynamically to the second panel . Everything is fine to this point but the problem is with the listeners. In early stages, I registered the event listeners for these comboboxes individually for every element in the array and it resulted in 900 lines of codes, but it worked fine and all my results were correct. To enhance my code I'm trying to write a for loop for registering the events for the comboboxes and so far I couldn't succeed.

I tried to write the handling code as anonymous inner class and as separate inner class, Here is my last try:

```
for(i = 0; i<courseN;i++)
            {
                hourCombo[i].addItemListener(new HoursHandler());
                gradeCombo[i].addItemListener(new GradeHandler());
            }


public class HoursHandler implements ItemListener
{
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {   
                String hour;
                hour = (String) hourCombo[i].getSelectedItem();
                currentHour[i]=Integer.parseInt(hour);
                aquiredHours=aquiredHours+currentHour[i] prevHour[i];
                prevHour[i]=currentHour[i];
            }
        }
}


public class GradeHandler implements ItemListener
{
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
            {
            String grade;
            grade=(String) gradeCombo[i].getSelectedItem();

            switch(grade)
            {
            case "A+": 
                currentPoint[i]=5*currentHour[i];

                break;
            case "A": 
                currentPoint[i]= 4.75 * currentHour[i];
                break;
            case "B+": 
                currentPoint[i]= 4.5 * currentHour[i];
                break;
            case "B": 
                currentPoint[i]= 4 * currentHour[i];
                break;
            case "C+": 
                currentPoint[i]= 3.5 * currentHour[i];
                break;
            case "C": 
                currentPoint[i]= 3 * currentHour[i];
                break;
            case "D+": 
                currentPoint[i]= 2.5 * currentHour[i];
                break;
            case "D": 
                currentPoint[i]= 2 * currentHour[i];
                break;
            case "F":
                currentPoint[i]= 1 * currentHour[i];
                break;
        }
            aquiredPoints=aquiredPoints+currentPoint[i]-prevPoint[i];
            prevPoint[i]=currentPoint[i];
        }
        }
}
```

I get a NullPointerException for this statement:

```
                    hour = (String) hourCombo[i].getSelectedItem();
```

and everything goes wrong, none of my variables is updated and I cannot calculate the GPA..

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from the posted code what is wrong there. However, I assume that `i` is declared as an instance variable. In this case, the loop `for(i = 0; i<courseN;i++)` will change the value of this instance variable. Afterwards, **all** the listeners will internally use `i` with the last value that it received in the `for`-loop.

To circumvent this, you can declare an instance variable for *each listener instance*. So you can change your listener classes like this:

```
public class HoursHandler implements ItemListener
{
    private final int index;

    HoursHandler(int index)
    {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
    {
        // Use the "index" here:

        String hour = (String) hourCombo[index].getSelectedItem();
        currentHour[index]=Integer.parseInt(hour);       
        ...
    }
}
```

(similarly, introduce such an index for the `GradeHandler`).

Then, when you create the listeners, you can pass to each instance the index that it refers to:

```
// Note: "i" is declared here, and should NO longer
// be an instance variable!
for(int i = 0; i<courseN;i++)
{
    hourCombo[i].addItemListener(new HoursHandler(i)); // Use "i" as "index"
    gradeCombo[i].addItemListener(new GradeHandler(i)); // Use "i" as "index"
}
```

I assume that there might be some more elegant solutions, but this is *one* possible solution, solely based on the code that you provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I get the problem I created now.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `i` is a member field in your outer class.  When your listener is executed, and your listener

```
hour = (String) hourCombo[i].getSelectedItem();
```

this statement will use whatever value `i` happens to be in this outer class.  And after you execute your `for` loop, `i` will probably be equal to `courseN`, unless there's something else changing it somewhere else.  In any case, it doesn't use the value that `i` held when you set up the listener, because you did nothing to tell it to use that value.

A simple way to fix this is to construct your listeners by giving it the index you want them to use:

```
public class HoursHandler implements ItemListener
{
    private final int index;
    public HoursHandler(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
        {   
            String hour;
            hour = (String) hourCombo[index].getSelectedItem();
```

and use `index` instead of `i` everywhere in the listener.  When you construct the listener, it will store the index you want, and then the code will use that instead of the current value of `i`.  Similarly for `GradeHandler`.  Then

```
for(i = 0; i<courseN;i++)
        {
            hourCombo[i].addItemListener(new HoursHandler(i));
            gradeCombo[i].addItemListener(new GradeHandler(i));
        }
```

Note that the index you want the listeners to use is now passed as a parameter to the listeners' constructors.

**EDITED** to use `final` on the index member--plagiarized from Marco13's good idea.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I have a clear idea now of my problem.